# How to use awk to sort records in a csv file

Tags: awk

I would like to use shell script (Awk) to sort records in a CSV file. Here is what my file looks like:

```
   A       B       C      D        E      F        G      H       I     J        K      L     M    N
1 14000   37.1    425.9   1       12687   1       425     2
2 14000   41.0    4280    1       4292    1       4266.1  1     425.9   1       425     1    180   1
3 14000   37.1    425.9   1       12687   1       425     2
4 14000   192.1   180     1       12687   1       425.9   1     425     1       90      1
```

1. Sorting rows. Descending power
2. Skipping columns A & B
3. Columns C & D is a pair.
   Columns E & F is a pair.
   Columns G & H is a pair.
   Columns I & J is a pair.
   Columns K & L is a pair.
   Columns M & N is a pair.
   The columns will be more or less, depends on the results that I get, but still in pairs.

For example:
Looking at row 1:

```
 A       B       C      D        E      F        G      H 
14000   37.1    425.9   1       12687   1       425     2
```

The output of row 1 will be:

```
14000   37.1    12687   1       425.9   1       425     2
```

Column E (12687) is bigger than column C (425.9), so move columns E & F to columns C & D.

I've thought about using string array to store pairs first, and then sorting. But no idea how to implement it. Can anyone give me ideas?

---

[Update]

I've solved the problem. Here is my solution:

```
#!/bin/bash

[ -f columnsOneTwo.csv ] && rm -fv columnsOneTwo.csv
[ -f eachpair.csv ] && rm -fv eachpair.csv
[ -f sorted.csv ] && rm -fv sorted.csv

filename="matched.csv"
linenum=1
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]
do
  #print the content in line
  echo "$line"

  #calculate how many columns in each line
  columns=`awk -F ',' -v v=$linenum 'NR==v{print NF}' matched.csv`

  echo $line | cut -d ',' -f1-2 > columnsOneTwo.csv

  getPairs=`echo $line | cut -d ',' -f3-`
  #get each pair from getPairs
  #start from the third column
  for i in `seq 1 2 $((columns-2))` 
  do
      getEachPair=`echo $getPairs | cut -d ',' -f$i-$((i+1))` #C&D, E&F ...
      echo $i ":" $getEachPair
      #Deal with each pair, store in eachpair.csv
      echo $getEachPair >> eachpair.csv
  done
  #Integrate into a same file (sorted.csv)
  cat columnsOneTwo.csv eachpair.csv | sort -n -k1nr,1 -t ',' | tr '\n' ',' >> sorted.csv
  echo "" >> sorted.csv
  linenum=$((linenum+1))
  rm -rfv eachpair.csv #remove old each pair file
done < $filename
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, on SO its highly encouraged for questioners to put their efforts in form of code(there is nothing right or wrong here, we all are here to learn), you could use Stack's search functionality and start over put your tried things in your question and you will start getting answers on your question IMHO, cheers and happy learning.

Comment: Awk is not very suitable for parsing CSV; it can be done but it's cumbersome if you want to handle quoting and multiline records. This should be very easy in a language with built-in CSV support, like Python with the `csv` module from the standard library which is part of every install.

Comment: @tripleee The reason why I'm doing sorting is because I need to delete duplicate rows, which are from a csv file. This is just a small part of my bash file. I'm not sure if I can use Python to deal with it.

Comment: It's curious that you show the data without any commas, but you use `awk -F ',' …` in your processing.  It seems that the data you show isn't what your data file looks like.  CSV originally meant 'comma-separated values'; it now often means 'character-separated values' (so you don't need TSV for 'tab-separated values', and PSV for 'pipe-separated values' and so on — TSV is used sometimes; PSV is not, AFAIK).

Comment: Your question should remain strictly a question. Please post the answer as an answer instead, and eventually accept that once you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That script executes an awful lot of commands to achieve what a single `awk` command can achieve.  This code doesn't use a fancy sort algorithm — but it can easily be improved.

This is the program file (`script.awk`):

```
{
    #print NR ": [", $0, "]"
    f12 = $1 FS $2
    n = 0
    for (i = 3; i < NF; i += 2)
    {
      p1[n] = $i
      p2[n++] = $(i+1)
    }
    #for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    #  print p1[i], p2[i]
    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
        {
            if (p1[i] < p1[j] || (p1[i] == p1[j] && p2[i] < p2[j]))
            {
                t = p1[i]
                p1[i] = p1[j]
                p1[j] = t
                t = p2[i]
                p2[i] = p2[j]
                p2[j] = t
            }
        }
    }
    #printf "%d: [%s", NR, f12
    printf "%s", f12
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        printf "%s%s%s%s", FS, p1[i], FS, p2[i]
    print ""
    #print "]"
}
```

This is the data file (`data`).  It is the data shown in the question converted back to a comma-separated format.

```
14000,37.1,425.9,1,12687,1,425,2
14000,41.0,4280,1,4292,1,4266.1,1,425.9,1,425,1,180,1
14000,37.1,425.9,1,12687,1,425,2
14000,192.1,180,1,12687,1,425.9,1,425,1,90,1
```

This is the command executed and the output:

```
$ awk -F, -f script.awk data
14000,37.1,12687,1,425.9,1,425,2
14000,41.0,4292,1,4280,1,4266.1,1,425.9,1,425,1,180,1
14000,37.1,12687,1,425.9,1,425,2
14000,192.1,12687,1,425.9,1,425,1,180,1,90,1
$
```

For each line of input, the script captures fields A & B into `f12`.  It saves the remaining pairs into the `p1` and `p2` arrays.  It then sorts the arrays in parallel, in descending order of values in `p1` and (in case of ties on `p1`) descending order of `p2`.  It then prints the result line.  The comment lines show the debug printing used during development.

The script has no error checking.  It blithely assumes that the data is correctly formatted and uses only numeric data in each field.

The code shown in the question runs many commands for each line of input.  That will inevitably be slower (probably by an order of magnitude or more) than the single `awk` script.  Casual testing with the script in the question showed it took around 0.155 to 0.160s to process the 4 lines of data.  Equally casual testing with the single `awk` script showed it took around 0.003 to 0.004s to process the same 4 lines of data.  That's close to 40 times faster.  Granted, there's quite a lot of verbose debugging output in the script in the question.  Nevertheless, the results are indicative.  I also tested a file with 40 lines of data (10 copies of the 4 lines shown).  The `bash` script took between 1.4 and 1.5 seconds to run; the `awk` script took between 0.004 and 0.005 seconds to run.  YMMV!

Comment: I note that the script in the question generates the output file, `sorted.csv`, with a trailing comma on each line. The `awk` script does not generate a trailing comma.  When the trailing comma is removed (or added), the output files from the two commands are identical.